# Why does Selenium give Safari 11's version as 13605?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver, browserstack

I'm using BrowserStack for Selenium testing and sending this set of capabilities for testing with Safari 11:

> os=OS X
>   os_version=High Sierra
>   browser=Safari
>   browser_version=11

But when I check the browser properties in Java code...

```
System.out.println("Browser is: " + driver.getCapabilities().getBrowserName());
System.out.println("Version is: " + driver.getCapabilities().getVersion());
System.out.println("Platform is: " + driver.getCapabilities().getPlatform());
```

I get this:

> Browser is: safari
>   Version is: 13605.3.8
>   Platform is: MAC

Other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE give me the kinds of version numbers I'd expect.  So does Safari 12: 12.1.1.

So where does this 13605 for Safari 11 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using *Safari v11* and `driver.getCapabilities().getVersion()` is returning **13605.3.8** it seems to be a bug.

As per [MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15675/apple-safari/version-history) one of the past version of Safari was:

```
Version 12.0, released Sep 18, 2018
```

and the previous version to it was:

```
Version 11.1.2: (13605.3.8)
```

Of coarse `getVersion()` should have extracted **11.1.2**

Comment: A Selenium bug or a Safari bug?

Comment: @RyanLundy As you have experienced  `getVersion()` works perfecto with Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE. So I suspect, the issue should have been with in _Selenium_ client for the _Safari_ switch case.

Comment: SafarDriver is where this comes from

Answer (score 1):

The Safari version you see when running the command "driver.getCapabilities().getVersion()" on Safari v11.1.2 is the build number associated with that particular Safari version. For more information refer [here](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/26666/safari-version-and-build-version-search).

You will see the same version being returned when running the command "driver.getCapabilities().getVersion()" on a local Safari v11.1.2 too.

Attaching a screenshot of my local Safari v11.1.2 (13605.3.8).[image]

Comment: Any idea why it would be returning the build number rather than the version number?  This is inconsistent with every other browser.  Is this a Selenium bug or a peculiarity of Safari?